# How do you check what parameter was passed onto a function?

Tags: c++, function, parameter-passing

I want to check what is the name of the variable that is passed onto a function, so like:

```
void foo(char v[8][8]) {
    if(name of passed array == 'v')
        //do something
    else if(name of passed array == 'w')
        //do something else
```

Would this even work?
I have seen the same question asked but it was for python and they used "is" (a keyword). Is there an equivalent for c++?

Comment: do you mean variable name or variable type?

Comment: that's impossible. `v` is the name of the variable in the function. what you pass from outside doesn't exist in this scope. good c++ books reference should show up somewhere in the comment section. Consider reading them first, C++ is not that simple language

Comment: No, C++ is different than python. The equivalent of "keyword is" would be maybe pointer comparison, but that doesn't make much sense. Explain what are you trying to do exactly, because it's hard to tell from the bad example. If you need to pass a 2-D array to the function, start with `std::vector<std::vector<char> >`.

Comment: Usually if one wants to get the name of the variable or the whole expression as in the code, they use macros

Comment: @IłyaBursov the variable name

Comment: @Strasse34 why do you want to check variable name? what if caller change name later?

Comment: @IłyaBursov I only want the function to do something only if the name is v

Comment: @Strasse34 then pass separate boolean flag as argument, do not rely on argument name, as it can be easily changed during refactoring and thus will break your logic

Comment: C++ is a huge fan of runtime efficiency. Storing the names of things has a cost and the computer doesn't care what we meatbags call a function, or a variable for that matter, the only thing the computer cares about is where it is in memory. Those nice, helpful names that make code readable to humans are replaced fairly early in the build process in order to make thigs easier for the computer.

Comment: That leads to another little side note: Code describes program behaviour, not computer instructions. The compiler takes your descriptions and produces the best possible set of instructions to provide that behaviour. And those instructions might not look much like what you wrote.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. What are you trying to solve with this?

Answer (score 0):

C++ cant do this.

If you really want to do this, create a struct with the meta-data:

```
struct A
{
char name;
char v[8][8];
}

void foo(A &a)
{
 if(a.name == 'v'){
 //do something
 }
 else(a.name == 'w')
 {
 //something else
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I expand my idea on macros, written in a comment by me previously:

```cpp
#define foo_wrapper(exp) \
if (0 == strcmp(#exp, "w")){...}\
foo(exp);
```

The sharp `#` stringifies the expression `exp`.

Here is info on stringification of expressions with macros: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.5/cpp/Stringification.html

Comment: Ah, yes, I was too quick. You can use strcmp. I will update.